# NSURLConnection caching and receiving data

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

Quick question: On the method

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

from the NSURLConnectionDataDelegate, if I don't append the data given by the method on my NSData, will it be lost? or does the connection save it somewhere as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not saved anywhere.  If you want to keep it, you must do so yourself.

Comment: But what about the default caching option in NSURLRequest?

Answer (score 0):

typically this method is where you would keep track of your data, with an NSMutableData instance variable:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [myData appendData:data];
}
```